# Git remove files on server not present on local

Tags: git, github

Often I would move files locally say from one folder to another. When committing to Git, I have to manually remove the files on the server that do not match a file path existing on my local repository.

How could I make this a less painful task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git commit -a` will automatically stage all modified and deleted files, so that your commit will reflect those changes.  It doesn't automatically add new files, though, which you will still need to do by hand.

You can also look at `git mv` and `git rm` to do things a little more smoothly - in the sense that they will act on the checkout and stage the results, so you only have one command to issue.

Comment: I usually use `git add .` and `git commit -m "because I can"`, will adding `-a` to the commit have any undesirable effects when using git like this?

Comment: Given the way you use git already, I think it will do what you want.  The behaviour is more or less equivalent to `git add .` for changes and deletes of files.